# limit of $(x^2+y^2)/y$ where $x$ and $y$ tend to 0

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I tried solving the limit of $(x^2+y^2)/y$, where both $x$ and $y$ tend to 0. Filling this in somewhere in a calculator says the limit does not exist, but I get that it tends to 0. Can someone explain to me why this limit does not exist?

Comment: What happens if you approach zero along the parabola $y=x^2$?

Comment: @GitGud Why do you say the limit exists?

Comment: @zhw. Something escaped me, still not sure what it is. Deleting my comment. **Edit:** Now I get it. the mistake I did is too embarrassing too share.

Comment: This is an interesting example to include in discussion of multi-dimensional limits.  The limit along all lines is zero, but that does not mean "the limit is zero".

Comment: How ridiculous, someone up voting zhw's comment even after I deleted my comment and admitted my mistake.

Comment: @GEdgar, can you explain why I need to plug in $y = x^2$?

Answer (score 0):

If $x=y^a$, the limit is 0 if $a=1$, $1$ if $a=1/2$, and $\infty$ if $a=1/3$.